# Is SSL with server certificate and client password possible?

Tags: ssl, encryption

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3107645/1559672 it's possible to set up ssl connection without user verification.

I think the answer to my question would be yes but can't find anything to confirm/reject it.

The idea is that the server has a certificate that the client can verify via a CA. Then client generates some secret and encrypts with server's public key. Based on this shared secret they generate 'key material' for encryption/decryption. After they have the secured connection, client can verify itself with username/password.

Is it possible like this? if yes, please show me some example or proof.
If not, why not?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. SSL/TLS has two parts to it: *Verification of identity* and *encryption*. Identity verification works by presenting a certificate which has been signed by a trusted 3rd party. Encryption works independently of that and "is just there" when using TLS. – If the client does not present a certificate, there's nothing TLS can do for identification. You're free to confirm your own username/password scheme over a TLS secured connection (i.e. what basically any login form does these days).

Comment: *"Then client generates some secret and encrypts with server's public key. Based on this shared secret they generate 'key material' for encryption/decryption."* - Yes, that's how all cipher suites with RSA, but without ECDH/DH work. *"client can verify itself with username/password"* what does that mean?

Comment: The answer you have cited is completely incorrect.

Comment: "Then client generates some secret and encrypts with server's public key. Based on this shared secret they generate 'key material' for encryption/decryption." so at this point client and server can use a secure channel. and through this secure channel, the client would send the username/password that the server checks if correct or not.

Comment: @EJP my idea was based on the quote inside that cited answer that comes from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: You're getting too lost in the details of TLS. A certificate serves the purpose of confirming an identify ("am I really talking to example.com right now?"); the client requires the server to have a valid cert before it talks to it. Then magic happens, and you now have a secure connection between the client and the server. Over this secure connection you can send any secret data you wish and do with it whatever you want. Again, every trivial login form on the web these days does exactly this.

Comment: @BalazsVarhegyi [Wikipedia is not a reliable source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipedia_is_not_a_reliable_source). The normative reference in this case is RFC 2246 and its successors. I've corrected the Wikipedia article, which had already been corrected numerous times since the answer you cited was posted.

Comment: @deceze so first TLS is set up using server's certificate, then through this channel user sends secret data (user/pwd). (Actually this is what I tried to describe in my original question.) The reason of confusion was because of RabbitMQ doc: https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html "Connecting without validating certificates" 's example code doesnt define what server certificates or RootCAs are accepted. (RabbitMQ cert is self signed) So I don't get how TLS is set up without that? 
Could form your previous post as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The reason of confusion was because of RabbitMQ doc: rabbitmq.com/ssl.html "Connecting without validating certificates" 's example code doesnt define what server certificates or RootCAs are accepted. (RabbitMQ cert is self signed) So I don't get how TLS is set up without that?

Encryption does not depend on certificates. And a self-signed certificate is still a valid certificate.

The purpose of certificates is to prove the identity of the remote peer. Can you really be sure you're talking to the server you think you're talking to and that your connection isn't currently being hijacked? This is ensured by the server presenting a certificate only it could have (public/private key crypto validates this, only the server should have the private key for the certificate; trust/security here depends on the server keeping its private key to itself).

How do you trust the certificate? Well, you may have a copy of it in your trusted certificate store. You'd do this with a self-signed certificate: just put it in your trusted store; since you (presumably) know where it came from, it's trustworthy.
Since this is unrealistic for every public site on the web, a [*public key infrastructure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) exists which allows you to trust a limited known number of certificate authorities which can sign certificates of arbitrary unknown parties, and you can indirectly trust those heretofore unknown certificates.

Having said all this, encryption is a separate component and an encrypted, secured connection can be set up with or without the *identity verification* that certificates provide.

Comment: Note that this a very very high level overview, and that Wikipedia is a bad source if you really want to understand this in detail. It's just supposed to give you a general understanding.

Comment: yes thank you that's what I need right now. "How do you trust the certificate? Well, you may have a copy of it in your trusted certificate store." The rabbitmq example code connects to my RabbitMQ successfully through that port but I don't give the  self-signed server certificate to my rabbit-client in that example code.(so it's not added to the truststore). Why?

Comment: I guess it simply sets up TLS with server cert but without verifying it.

Comment: I don't know the specifics, but either the certificate is hardcoded in the client, or it simply doesn't care.